# C Pointer becomes NULL in loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have found many 'pointer becomes NULL' questions, but struggling to apply the answers to my problem

I have 3 nested structs. Struct `A` should contain an array of struct `B`, which contains a single struct `C` which itself should contain an array of `int`:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t *data;
    uint16_t nData;
    uint16_t dataOffset;        
} Window;

typdef struct {
    Window *window;
    const char *datasetPath;
} Dataset

typedef struct {
    char *id;
    uint8_t count;
    Dataset *datasets;
} DatasetGroup;
```

I have a `new` function for the structs:

```
int8_t dataset_new(Dataset *ds, const char *datasetPath, uint16_t winSize){
    ds->datasetPath = datasetPath;
    ds->window = malloc(sizeof(*(ds->window));
    ds->window->data = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * (winSize));
    return 0;

int8_t datasetgroup_new(DatasetGroup *dg, char *id){
    dg->id = id;
    dg->count = 0;
    dg->datasets = malloc(sizeof(*(dg->datasets)) * 255);
}
```

And I have an `add` function to add a `Dataset` to the `DatasetGroup`:

```
int8_t datasetgroup_add(DatasetGroup *dg, const char *filePath, uint16_t winSize){
       // Create the dataset
       Dataset ds; 
       dataset_new(&ds, filePath, winSize);

       // Add the dataset to the dataset array
       dg->datasets[dg->count] = ds;
       dg->count++;
       return 0;
       }
```

I then iterate through the datasets in order to populate the data, doing stuff like:

```
     for (i = 0 ; i < datasetCount ; i++){
         Dataset *ds = &(dg->datasets[i])
```

Always on the 2nd interation, the `data` array becomes a null pointer:
             data = ds->window->data

I understand that I have done something wrong passing pointers around(?) but I'm not sure what precisely I have done wrong....

Comment: The posted code looks OK to me. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RSahu I'll have to spend a bit of time cutting stuff out to try and get it to the minimum that still causes it.... (probably a good exercise any way). I'll work on it....

Comment: The error is probably elsewhere. Get your program running in a debugger. Identify the address of the pointer that eventually becomes null, and set a data breakpoint on that address (i.e. something like `&dg->datasets[1].window->data`).

Comment: It looks like in `datasetgroup_add()` you are declaring `ds` on the stack, which can/will get overwritten once `ds` goes out of scope when you return from `datasetgroup_add()`.  Try moving `ds` to the heap.

Comment: Im not losing  `ds`, which can still be accessed..i only lose `ds->window->data`if that makes any difference

Comment: "losing" is relative, that address in memory still exists, but the addresses saved in `ds.window` and `ds.datasetPath` are getting overwritten, i.e. the memory location where you are declaring `ds` is being reused for other stuff.  Try changing `ds` to a pointer that you then `malloc` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine. So check another part of the code. You can debug code line by line so you can understand the segment which is creating this error.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Error was elsewhere..a simple mistake when allocating memory meant I wasn't allocating memory for more than 1 structure (I thought I was)